# Creating and initializing a class derived from a dictionary

Tags: c#

Say I have the following class definition:

```
public class MyClass : Dictionary<int, string>
{
}
```

How can I create one from an expression something like this (which doesn't work)?

```
MyClass myClass = myList.ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.value);
```

Comment: The real question is why do you inherit a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Its a DTO created in another assembly I cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`implicit operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) can't be used in this case because it violates `cs0553 user-defined conversion from base class not allowed`

You must create a constructor

```
public class MyClass : Dictionary<int, string>
{
    public MyClass(Dictionary<int, string> dict)
    {
        foreach(var entry in dict)
        {
            this.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myList.ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.value));
```

or create a static helper to create an instance from `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.1) returns a `Dictionary` object, but you want to assign to a `MyClass`. Just because `MyClass` is a derived type, does not allow any automatic conversion, the same as `MyClass cls = new Dictionary<int, string>()` is not allowed.

If you want a similar syntax, you could create your own extension methods, for example assuming `MyClass` has a constructor accepting the dictionary:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static MyClass ToMyClass<TSource>(this Enumerable enumerable, Func<TSource,int> keySelector, Func<TSource,string> elementSelector)
    {
        return new Myclass(enumerable.ToDictionary(keySelector, elementSelector));
    }
}

...
MyClass myClass = myList.ToMyClass(l => l.Key, l => l.value);
```

This also works if `MyClass` contains a `Dictionary` rather than extending it, or if it even converts it to an entirely different format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by create and use of simple method. Try this:

```
public static MyClass ConvertToMyClass(Dictionary<int, string> dictionary)
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            obj.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

And, use as

```
MyClass myClass = Program.ConvertToMyClass(myList.ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.value));
```